# Django Simple Push Notification to IOS

Tags: python, django, apple-push-notifications

I want to create simple function for sending push notification to IOS devices. Inside my model i am storing Device_type and Device_token

for Android i had written simple code using requests like below

```
import requests, json

def send_push_notif_android(device_token,title,msg):

    payload = {
        "to" : device_token,
        "notification" : {
        "title": title,
        "text": msg
      }
     }

     url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"

     header = {
        "Content-Type":"application/json",
        "Authorization":"key = <app key>"
      }
     requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=header)
```

I dont know how to do it for IOS
i had generated Certificates.pem file and kept it in my root folder.
Can someone tell me how to write simplest example like this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for [django-push-notifications](https://github.com/jazzband/django-push-notifications)

Comment: I had my own custom Table in database where i am storing Device_token and Device_type.  I tried django-push-notifications but it creates it own table which is not my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Since this questions still turns up in search, [here](https://gist.github.com/Hiyorimi/41bc8cf1fb913cb9eb3f70d6e9587f5d) is 2020 update version of Python3 HTTP2-compatible script to send push notifications.